# Internet Explorer Object expected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Internet Explorer Object expected error LINE: 64

**The code works in Firefox and Chrome.**

I keep getting an Internet explorer object expected error. I removed the afflicted code and it just keeps going
until any code after line 64 is gone.

The problem starts at line 64 which is the below code:

**AFFLICTED CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    preload(preloadi);
});
```

**ALL JQUERY CODE:**

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>           
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

/* -------------------------------- Preload images function for speed*/

    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $('body').addClass("loading");
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
        $('body').removeClass("loading");
    }

/* -------------------------------- Generic functionality function */

    function transformImage(classCSS, original, link, backArray, count, prevClass) {
        var back = '<div id="back"><div id="_' + backArray[backArray.length-1] + '"></div></div><div class="_0"></div><div class="_1"></div><div class="_4"></div><a id="contact" href="mailto:pbn@casa.gov.au"></a><a id="rightlink" target="_blank" href="http://www.casa.gov.au/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD::pc=PC_101078"></a>';

        link[prevClass] = window.original;
        window.original = link[classCSS];

        if (classCSS != '0') { link[classCSS] += back; }

        $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 0.25, function () {

            $('.inter').html(link[classCSS]);


            $('.inter').css({
                'background-image': 'url("' + classCSS + '.png")'
            });
            $('.inter').fadeTo(250, 1.00);
        });
    }

/* -------------------------------- Variables */
    var preloadi = [
        '1.png',
        '2.png'
        ];  
    var backArray = [];
    var prevClass = '0';
    var classCSS = '0';
    var count = 0;
    original = '<div class="_2"></div><div class="_3"></div>';
    var link = [
    '<div class="_2"></div><div class="_3"></div>',
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd'
    ];

/* -------------------------------- Event handlers */

    $(document).ready(function () {
        preload(preloadi);
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.inter [class]', function (event) {
        $('.' + this.classCSS + 't').toggle(event.type === 'mouseenter');
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#selectContainer [id]', function () {
    backArray[count] = classCSS;
    count += 1;
    prevClass = classCSS;

    classCSS = $("select").val();
    transformImage(classCSS, original, link, backArray, count, prevClass); 
    })

    $(document).on('click', '.inter [class], .inter #back [id]', function () {

    if (this.id) { 
    count -= 1; 
    backArray.pop(count);  
    } else { 
    backArray.push(classCSS);
    count += 1;
    }

    prevClass = classCSS;
    classCSS = (this.id || this.className).substr(1);
    transformImage(classCSS, original, link, backArray, count, prevClass); 
    })  

    </script>
```

Comment: Some of your selectors are unusual. What is `'#selectContainer [id]'`? The `[id]` part selects elements with an `id` attribute. Is the idea that you're selecting all child elements of `#selectContainer` that have `id` attributes? Similar question for `'.inter [class], .inter #back [id]'`: Are we selecting all children of `.inter` that have `class` attributes, along with all children of `.inter #back` that have `id` attributes? What is all this about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document-ready handler is too short.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   preload(preloadi);
});  // Document ready ends here.
```

As a result, everything below it is executing before the DOM is ready.

Move the closing `});` below all your event handler code and it should work, subject to any other coding errors there might be.

What you should end up with is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  preload(preloadi);

  $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.inter [class]', function (event) {
    $('.' + this.classCSS + 't').toggle(event.type === 'mouseenter');
 });

 // more initialisation code...

});  // end of $(document).ready()

// No more code here.
```

Comment: I moved the ready function below the event handler code. The IE error just goes to the next line. Which is: "    $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.inter [class]', function (event) {
        $('.' + this.classCSS + 't').toggle(event.type === 'mouseenter');
    });"

Comment: Did you move the whole function, or just the closing brackets? You need to enclose your event handlers in the ready function. If you don't, IE will try to execute them too soon.

Comment: I did, the error remained plus a few more object expected errors. Doesn't  $(document).on wait until the dom is ready? Or does that not work in IE?

Comment: No - it doesn't wait. That's why you enclose all that code in $(document).ready(function() { // All your initialisation code });

Comment: Wrapping the code like described above. 3 object expected errors now exist. 1 on the first line of the script (Blank line)  and the other two on the start of the .ready function.

Comment: Well now you have me stumped. I pasted this code into a skeleton document here and loaded it into IE8. No errors appeared, which suggests your problem is now elsewhere, but I can't even guess at that.

Comment: @sephiith Did you copy any part of this code from another website?

Comment: @sephiith Because when that is done, sometimes, hidden characters are copied, which would explain the error, in my opinion.

Comment: @Daealus It's probably the smallest thing that is causing all this.